# Javascript form validation for user account

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation

I am creating an account creation form and using javascript to validate it. I was hoping I could get some help fixing and optimizing it. It returns incorrect alerts and has some other problems. Any improvements are welcome and I appreciate any advice I get. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Create an Accoount</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateform() {
    //vars
    var username = document.forms["usercreate"]["username"].value;
    var email = document.forms["usercreate"]["email"].value;
    var pass1 = document.forms["usercreate"]["pass1"].value;
    var pass2 = document.forms["usercreate"]["pass2"].value;

    //null check
    if(username = "") {
        alert ("You forgot the user name");
        return false;
    }
    if(email = "") {
        alert ("You forgot the email address");
        return false;
    }
    if(pass1 = "") {
        alert ("You forgot a password address");
        return false;
    }
    if(pass2 = "") {
        alert ("You forgot a password address");
        return false;
    }

    if (username.length < 3 || username.length > 15) {
        alert("User name is too short (under 3) or too big (over 15)");
        return false;
    }
    if (pass1 != pass2) {
        alert ("Passwords don't match");
        return false;
    }
    if (pass1.length < 4) {
        alert ("Your is password is too short (under 4)");
        return false;
    }
    //email check
    var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Account Creation</h1>
<form name="usercreate" action="usercreate.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform();">
<p><label for="username">Pick a user name (must be at least three letters characters)<br />
<input type="text" name="username" value="username"/><br />
<label for="email">Enter your email address:<br />
<input type="text" name="email" value="email"/><br /> <!-- check this -->
<label for="pass1">Create a password: <br />
<input type="password" name="pass1" /><br />
<label for="pass2">Retype the password:<br />
<input type="password" name="pass2" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Create Account"/><br />
</form>
</p></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is that you've used the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `===` (or `==`):

```
if(username = "") {

// should be

if (username === "") {

// (and similar for the other fields)
```

The way you had it you were actually *changing* `username` to be an empty string, and then the if test was evaluating the result of that expression which as an empty string is "falsy" so the corresponding alert would never be shown.

Comment: thanks, that's such a simple mistake but I never would have thought of  it. Never the less, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2rda5/1/)

```
function validateform() {
//vars
var username = document.forms["usercreate"]["username"].value;
var email = document.forms["usercreate"]["email"].value;
var pass1 = document.forms["usercreate"]["pass1"].value;
var pass2 = document.forms["usercreate"]["pass2"].value;
var isFilled=true;
var msg="";
//null check
if(username == "") {
    msg+="You forgot the user name\n";
    isFilled=false;
}
if(email == "") {
    msg+="You forgot the email address\n";
    isFilled=false;
}
if(pass1 == "") {
    msg+="You forgot a password address\n";
    isFilled=false;
}
//if(pass2 == "") {
    //msg+="You forgot a password address\n";
    //isFilled=false;
//}

if (username.length < 3 || username.length > 15) {
    msg+="User name is too short (under 3) or too big (over 15)\n";
    isFilled=false;
}
if (pass1 != pass2) {
    msg+="Passwords don't match\n";
    isFilled=false;
}
if (pass1.length < 4) {
    msg+="Your is password is too short (under 4)\n";
    isFilled=false;
}
//email check
var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
    msg+="Not a valid e-mail address\n";
    isFilled=false;
}
if(!isFilled) {
    alert(msg);
}
return isFilled;

}​
```

Comment: Nice to combine the messages into a single alert - you could make this slightly shorter by removing the `isFilled` variable and at the end just `return msg === "";`.

Comment: Thanks and I appreciate your advise. :-) Don't you think it's important to return the true/false to make sure whether it should be submited or not depending on the return value of 'validateform' function as because in the form it's onclick="return validateform()";

Comment: The expression `msg === ""` evaluates to true or false: if `msg` is still an empty string we know there were no errors so it returns true, otherwise it returns false...

Comment: Oh! Really appreciate your advise.